# Retrieving data from Firebase to Google Maps using Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I have successfully stored and retrieve the data from Firebase to my application. The console logs shows the data that is being retrieved. But in the html code, it shows undefined when I am trying to show the data in the infoWindow.

Some examples:

The information given in the console log. Getting the data from Firebase and the marker showing in Google Maps:

```
    *new locations:  
    Array(4)
    0: {lng: 103.991701, lat: 1.348758, timestamp: 1591880775484}
    1: {timestamp: 1591880805856, lng: 103.799669, lat: 1.4584}
    2: {timestamp: 1591880807857, lat: 1.282306, lng: 103.823246}
    3: {lat: 1.366623, timestamp: 1591881216351, lng: 103.672609}
    length: 4
    __proto__: Array(0)*
```

I can't show the images here, but for the info window, the value retrieved for the latitude and longitude is undefined.

Here is my marker-map.page.ts page:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { MarkersService } from '../services/markers.service';
    import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import { ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

    import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
    import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

    const { Geolocation } = Plugins;

    declare var google: any;


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-marker-map',
      templateUrl: './marker-map.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./marker-map.page.scss'],
    })
    export class MarkerMapPage {


      @ViewChild('map', { read: ElementRef, static: false }) mapElement: ElementRef;
      infoWindows: any = [];
      map: any;
      markers: any = [];

      locations: Observable<any>;
      locationsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
      user = null;
      watch = null;

      isTracking = false;

      constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afs: AngularFirestore) {
        this.anonLogin();
        //this.markerData = {} as MarkerData;
      }

      ionViewWillEnter() {
        this.loadMap();
      }

      loadMap() {
        let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.2902706, 103.851959);

        let mapOptions = {
          center: latLng,
          zoom: 5,
          disabledDefaultUI: false
        };
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
      }

      anonLogin() {
        this.afAuth.signInAnonymously().then(res => {
          this.user = res.user;
          console.log(this.user);

          this.locationsCollection = this.afs.collection(
            `locations/${this.user.uid}/track`,
            ref => ref.orderBy('timestamp')
          );

          //load firebase data 
          this.locations = this.locationsCollection.valueChanges();
          //update map 
          this.locations.subscribe(locations => {
            console.log('new locations: ', locations);
            this.updateMap(locations);
          })
        });
      }

      updateMap(locations) {
        this.markers.map(marker => marker.setMap(null));
        this.markers = [];

        for (let loc of locations) {
          let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(loc.lat, loc.lng);

          let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            latitude: loc.lat,
            longitude: loc.lng,
            //animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            map: this.map
          });
          this.markers.push(marker);
          this.addInfoWindowToMarker(marker);
        }
      }

      addInfoWindowToMarker(loc) {
        let infoWindowContent = '<div id="content">' + 
                                  '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + 
                                  '<p>Latitude: ' + loc.lat + '<p>' +
                                  '<p> Longitude: ' + loc.lng + '<p>' +
                                '</div>';

        let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: infoWindowContent
        });

        loc.addListener('click', () => {
          this.closeAllInfoWindows();
          infoWindow.open(this.map, loc);
        });
        this.infoWindows.push(infoWindow);
      }

      closeAllInfoWindows() {
        for(let window of this.infoWindows) {
          window.close();
        }
      }

      addNewLocation(lat, lng, timestamp) {
        this.locationsCollection.add({
          lat,
          lng,
          timestamp
        });

        let position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        this.map.setCenter(position);
        this.map.setZoom(5);
      }

      ngOnInit() {
      }
    }
```

Any suggestions please help! Thank you.